# BeautifulSoup parsing - text to int

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup4 in python3 to try and parse out lowest fares from the following page: https://www.google.com/flights/explore/#explore;f=LAX;t=IAH,HOU;s=1;li=8;lx=12;d=2018-02-25

When i select a specific div tag and loop through the text, what code should i use to pull out the just the fares that have the $ next to it?

Here is what i used to pull the actual div's text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
best_price_tags = s.findAll('div', 'CTPFVNB-f-a')

best_prices = []
for tag in best_price_tags:
    print(tag.text)
```

returns:

```
"Explore flightsUp to 1 stopAirline FromLAX Los AngelesToHouston (all airports)Try: Europe, Mexico, CaribbeanTrip length8-12 daysLowest fares for trips of 8-12 daysPhoto: PanoramioBest price $101Nonstop $101Houston, TX$302$101$101Tue Feb 27 - Wed Mar 7FebruaryMarchApril"
```

I tried appending to a list but i got the following error:

```
best_prices = []
for tag in best_price_tags:
    best_prices.append(int(tag.text.replace('$','')))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Explore flightsUp to 1 stopAirline\xa0FromLAX Los AngelesToHouston (all airports)Try: Europe, Mexico, CaribbeanTrip length8-12 daysLowest fares for trips of 8-12 daysPhoto: PanoramioBest price 101Non
```

Comment: Use regex to obtain numbers with $